# Not able to send or receive messages on slack for a bot build using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, slack

I am trying to build a slack bot using the Microsoft Bot framework. I have created a bot using bot channels registration and also running a local node.js server. I tested my bot in web chat and it works fine but not working in slack. As soon as a user adds the bot to his apps list he needs to get a message welcome,  the welcome message appears in web chat but not in slack app.

```js
//importing npm packages
const express = require('express')
const {
  BotFrameworkAdapter,
  MemoryStorage,
  UserState
} = require('botbuilder')
const path = require("Path")
const {
  WelcomeBot
} = require("./WelcomeBot")
const {
  SlackAdapter
} = require('botbuilder-adapter-slack')
//environmental path variables file config
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env')
require('dotenv').config({
  path: ENV_FILE
})

//object creation
const app = express()
//An adapter object for botframeworkadapter
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
  appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
  appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
})

// const adapter = new SlackAdapter({
//     clientSigningSecret: process.env.SLACK_SECRET,
//     botToken: process.env.SLACK_TOKEN
// })

adapter.onTurnError = async(context, error) => {
  console.error(`\n [onTurnError] unhandled error: ${error}`)

  await context.sendTraceActivity('OnTurnError Trace', `${error}`, 'https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error', 'TurnError');
  await context.sendActivity('The bot encountered an error or bug')
  await context.sendActivity('To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code')
}


const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage()
const userState = new UserState(memoryStorage)
const bot = new WelcomeBot(userState)

app.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
  console.log("listening....")
})

app.get("/api/messages", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Connected")
})
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req)
  const {
    challenge
  } = req.body;
  res.send({
    challenge
  });
})
app.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
  adapter.processActivity(req, res, async(context) => {

    await bot.run(context)
  })
})
```

The above is my main server file and the next is a welcome function to welcome the user:

```js
const {
  ActionTypes,
  ActivityHandler,
  CardFactory,
  MessageFactory
} = require('botbuilder')
const WELCOMED_USER = 'welcomedUserProperty'
const quick_reply1 = require("./User-inputs/Quick_replies")
const cardActions = [{
  type: ActionTypes.PostBack,
  title: 'List all the tasks',
  value: 'List all the tasks',
  imageAltText: 'R'
}]

myvalues = ['in progress', 'in review', 'blocked', 'Done']


class WelcomeBot extends ActivityHandler {
  constructor(userState) {
    super()

    this.welcomedUserProperty = userState.createProperty(WELCOMED_USER)

    this.userState = userState

    this.onMessage(async(context, next) => {

      const text = context.activity.text.toLowerCase()
      switch (text) {
        case "list all the tasks":
          await context.sendActivity("Hello")
      }
      await next()
    })

    this.onMembersAdded(async(context, next) => {
      var reply = MessageFactory.suggestedActions(cardActions, 'What can I do for you today?');
      for (const idx in context.activity.membersAdded) {
        if (context.activity.membersAdded[idx].id != context.activity.recipient.id) {
          await context.sendActivity("Welcome to Jaas Slackbot")
          await context.sendActivity(reply);
        }
      }
    })
  }

  async run(context) {
    await super.run(context)


    await this.userState.saveChanges(context)
  }
}

exports.WelcomeBot = WelcomeBot;
```

The bot gets added to the workspace and have  also created a channel on bot registration channel azure but yet not working.

[image]

Comment: do you get any errors in the Dev Console(Ctrl+Shft+I) or on the network tab on Slack?https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/1181